# Checking even or odd on mips using Shift operators and bne

Tags: mips

I know I can check whether an integer is even if I shift right by 1, then shift left by 1 and the number stays as the original number.

My code isn't working as intended. This is my first time using MIPS and any help would be appreciated. I want to let the user input any number and my code will tell the user whether it is an even number.

```
.data
msg: .asciiz "even"
.text
.globl main

main:
li $v0, 5
syscall 
or $t0, $0, $v0 # Register $t0 gets input 

srl $t1 , $t0 , 1 #shift right by 1
syscall
sll $t1 , $t0 , 1 #shift left by 1
syscall


bne $t1, $t0, msg # if t1 equals t2 then it prints out even
syscall
```

Comment: Why do you have `syscall`s after the `srl` and `sll` instructions?

Comment: Should be `sll $t1 $t1 1`

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of strange things you're doing, and one easy-fix bug. But until you get the strange things fixed, you're going to be hozed.

First, like @markgz said, what are those syscalls supposed to be doing? Get rid of all of them except the one where you're getting a value from the user. Otherwise, you're going to get a number from the user over and over.

Second, branching to `msg` makes no sense. The memory at `msg` is an ASCIIZ string containing the characters `m`, `s`, `g`, and `\0`. These are not the 32 bits you are looking for. You need to branch to an instruction. I'm going to assume that labels isEven and isOdd exist somewhere.

The bug is what @Konrad said. Omitting the strange syscalls, your code is doing this:

```
srl $t1, $t0, 1 # shift *original val* right by 1 *and put in $t1*
sll $t1, $t0, 1 # shift *original val* left by 1 *and put in $t1*
bne $t1, $t0, isOdd # *will always be true because we just changed $t1 to be <> $t0*
```

So if you follow @Konrad's suggestion, it would look like this:

```
srl $t1, $t0, 1 # shift *original val* right by 1
sll $t1, $t1, 1 # shift *modified val* left by 1
bne $t1, $t0, isOdd # *Now we know if the value changed*
```

Note that I'm branching to isOdd. You claimed that if the values are different, then the number is even. That's incorrect.

As an aside, my favorite way to do this would be a little bit different:

```
andi $t1, $t0, 0x01
beq $t1, $zero, isEven
```

I'll leave it to you to figure out what I'm doing. One thing about your method: it fails if the most significant bit is set (which it will be if it's a negative signed integer).

Answer (score 0):

There are so many bugs in your code.

```
srl $t1 , $t0 , 1 #shift right by 1

syscall  # why you are using syscall here ??

sll $t1 , $t0 , 1 #shift left by 1--and should be sll $t1, $t1, 1 

syscall #and why also here ??

bne $t1, $t0, msg #wrong ,here you need to pass label as third operand for offset

li      $v0,4       # code 4 == print string
la      $a0,string  # $a0 == address of the string

syscall
```

Note: in spite of this you can just do & operation on any data with 0x1 and then check for the result is 0 (even) or 1 (odd)

I want also to share this link for programming tutorial on mips

http://chortle.ccsu.edu/AssemblyTutorial/index.html